# PhoneGap Media plugin error after file recording. Throw the Error

Tags: ios, cordova, phonegap-plugins

Inside my application I have 2 buttons record and play. All buttons is working normally but when I call mediaVar.stopRecord(); then x-code throw the error:

ERROR:     [0x19c154310] AVAudioSession.mm:646: -[AVAudioSession setActive:withOptions:error:]: Deactivating an audio session that has running I/O. All I/O should be stopped or paused prior to deactivating the audio session.

After this error all sounds isn't playing. 
This bug repeated  only on devices on emulator everything working perfect. My device: Ipad mini retina ios 8.3 . Guys please help me.

code:

```
record : function (fileName,onStartClb,onStopClb) {
    var self = this;
    if(this._recording) return false;
    onStartClb?onStartClb():null;
    this.createMedia(fileName,function(){
        self.mediaVar.startRecord();
        self.mediaVar.stop();
        setTimeout(function(){
            self.stopRecord();
            onStopClb?onStopClb():null;
        },self._recordDuration)
    });
},

stopRecord : function (clb) {
    this.mediaVar.stopRecord();
    this._recording = false;
    clb?clb():null;
    console.log('stop record')
},

play : function(fileName){
    var self = this;
    this.createMedia(fileName,function(){
        self.mediaVar.play()
    });
},

stop : function(fileName){
    var self = this;
    this.createMedia(fileName,function(){
        self.mediaVar.stop()
    });
},

initStartParameters : function(){
    var self = this;
    if(window.hasOwnProperty('LocalFileSystem')){
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, function(fileSystem){
            self.fileSystem = fileSystem;
        }, self.onError);
    }
},
```